# Issue in inserting the records using stored procedure with dynamic Id

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored procedure to get a list of records from TableA and insert those records into TableB. now i'm facing issue in this.

Here is my sp :

```
USE [Sample_DB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GOenter code here
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddStoredProcedure]

AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @ProcessedData AS TABLE (Name varchar(200),MaritalStatus varchar(200))     

  INSERT INTO @ProcessedData (Name ,MaritalStatus )
  SELECT Name,MaritalStatus from TableA where MaritalStatus='Male'   


  INSERT INTO [TableB] 
  (
       Id
      ,Name
      ,MaritalStatus        
  )
  SELECT ('M_'+cast(RIGHT(Year(getDate()),2) as varchar)+'_'+cast(REPLACE(STR((select MAX(Id)+1 from [TableA] where MaritalStatus='Male'),4),' ','0') as varchar)),Name,MaritalStatus FROM @ProcessedData 

END  

  TableA contains,

    Id   Name      MaritalStatus
    1    John      Male
    2    Sam       Male
    3    Seema     Female
```

when i execute the stored procedure, AddStoredProcedure

I'm getting the output as

```
 TableB contains,

    Id          Name     MaritalStatus
    M_13_0003      John     Male
    M_13_0003      Sam      Male
```

But i need as below;

```
TableB should be,

Id          Name     MaritalStatus
M_13_0003      John     Male
M_13_0004      Sam      Male
```

Thank you all in advance for your response.

Comment: Is there a specific order you want `Id`'s last part to increment? Would it make any difference if John was `0004` and Sam `0003`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use row_number function as:

```
     DECLARE @ProcessedData AS TABLE (Name varchar(200),MaritalStatus varchar(200))     

  INSERT INTO @ProcessedData (Name ,MaritalStatus )
  SELECT Name,MaritalStatus from TableA where MaritalStatus='Male'  

  DECLARE @IdMax int;
  SELECT @IdMax = MAX(Id)
  FROM [TableA] 
  WHERE MaritalStatus='Male';



  INSERT INTO [TableB] 
  (
       Id
      ,Name
      ,MaritalStatus        
  )     
  SELECT ('M_'+cast(RIGHT(Year(getDate()),2) as varchar)+'_'+cast(REPLACE(STR((row_number() over(Order by Name)+@IdMax ),4),' ','0') as varchar)),
  Name,MaritalStatus 
  FROM @ProcessedData
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (Id INT, Name VARCHAR(20), MaritalStatus VARCHAR(6))
DECLARE @TableB TABLE (Id VARCHAR(9), Name VARCHAR(20), MaritalStatus VARCHAR(6))
INSERT INTO @TableA (Id, Name, MaritalStatus) 
VALUES
(1, 'John', 'Male'),
(2, 'Sam', 'Male'),
(3, 'Seema', 'Female')


DECLARE @ProcessedData AS TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Name varchar(200),MaritalStatus varchar(200))     

INSERT INTO @ProcessedData (Name ,MaritalStatus )
SELECT Name
    ,MaritalStatus 
FROM @TableA 
WHERE MaritalStatus='Male'   


INSERT INTO @TableB (Id, Name, MaritalStatus)        
SELECT ('M_'+cast(RIGHT(Year(getDate()),2) as varchar)+'_'+cast(REPLACE(STR((select MAX(Id) from @TableA where MaritalStatus='Male')+Id,4),' ','0') as varchar))
    ,Name
    ,MaritalStatus 
FROM @ProcessedData 

SELECT * FROM @TableB
```

I've replaced your tables with table variables so it runs straight off the bat.
Is there any reason you want to start from 0003? This query will produce your desired output anyway, comment if you need changes.

Comment: Can't comment on other peoples answers, but the other answer will work for your test data, however if you moved the girl to be the 2nd person in table A, the Ids would be wrong in the output (i.e. if you had id1 and id100 as men, with ids 2-99 as women, in the new table the 2 records would have IDs 0003 and 0101). This query ensures each ID in the new table is 1 greater than the last.